# Calculating central elements of Universal Enveloping Algebras?

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Simply put, how do I calculate (in general) the central elements of the UEA of some Lie algebra given some desired degree in the algebra generators?

I know the so-called 'quadratic Casimir', of degree $2$, is 
$$
X_i X^i = \kappa_{ij}X^i X^j
$$
for the Killing form $\kappa_{ij}$. This is much faster than, say, writing out some arbitrary $A_{ij} X^i X^j$ and repeatedly applying the commutation relations until there are enough constraints on the $A_{ij}$ to create a central element.

But what about if I want some other central elements? For instance the 'cubic Casimir' might be an appropriate name for the central element of degree $3$.

I don't want to have to begin with a general $B_{ijk} X^i X^j X^k$ and compute from there, as this contains a potentially enormous number of third degree monomials. Even in the most elementary case of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$, this is extremely daunting.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: The most elementary case would be $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}$. In this case, the center is generated by the Casimir. There is a characterization of the center of semisimple Lie algebras in terms of Weyl-invariant polynomial functions on the Cartan subalgebra. I would look up Harish-Chandra isomorphism for more details.

Comment: Yes, $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is a smaller algebra than $\mathfrak{sl}_3$...but it doesn't have higher order Casimirs, which is why I used the latter as an example of something with a nontrivial 'cubic Casimir'. I will look up Harish-Chandra.